# Как делать редирект вместо 403 ошибки, если у пользователя нет достаточных прав

Tags: python, django

Есть страница, на которую должен быть доступ только у пользователей со статусом is_stuff. Для этих целей я сделал миксин:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class StaffOnlyMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    raise_exception = False
    login_url = '/auth/login/'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff
```

Подмешиваю этот миксин в соответствующий контроллер:

```py
class ManagerPanel(StaffOnlyMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        #Какие-то действия
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Поскольку raise_exception = False, я ожидаю вот такого поведения от контроллера:

1. Если пользователь не авторизован, то происходит редирект на login_url. Это работает нормально.
2. Если пользователь авторизован, но не is_stuff, то тоже происходит редирект на login_url. Но вот это почему-то не работает. Вместо этого происходит 403 ошибка и выдается соответствующая страница.

Как мне реализовать второй пункт?

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему, переопределив функцию handle_no_permission:

```py
class StaffOnlyMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect(self.login_url)
```

А сбила с толку меня книга Дронова про Джанго 2.1, потому что там этот момент не совсем правильно описан.